# HTML table cell id - some generating static others dynamic

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following Jquery code:

```
$('#tableCellId').click(function () {
           //stuff
            });
```

Which was working fine and triggering, and after I had done some more work on the backend I began testing and saw this wasn't firing at all. I checked from the console and saw that the cell's id was being changed to a dynamically generated one i.e.:

```
<td id="ctl00_MainContent_tbTab_tbPanel_AccordionPane3_content_tableCellId" class="AddNew">+</td>
```

I noticed this problem occurring the same way after working fine initially, but with the cell's table element. Fine, I can use `"ClientIDMode = static"`.

`clientidmode="static"` isn't something I can apply to the cells, and wouldn't want to anyway. Why are the id's all of a sudden being generated dynamically? Is there an easy way to prevent this from happening?

I know that the ID can be dynamic if the cell is added dynamically. There are cells in this table which are, but this isn't and hasn't been one of them.

**Edit: full table**

```
<table id="tblMyTable" class="MyTableClass">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:90%;vertical-align:top;">
            <table ClientIDMode="Static" id="tblMyTable1" runat="server" class="TableClass" style="-moz-min-width:600px; -ms-min-width:600px; -o-min-width:600px; -webkit-min-width:600px; min-width:600px; width:100%;">
                <tr class="rowClass">
                    <td><div><input name="inputName" value="Name"></input></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="AddNew" colspan="42"> + </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="addType1" class="AddNew">+</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table ClientIDMode="Static" id="tblMyTable2" runat="server" class="TableClass" style="-moz-min-width:600px; -ms-min-width:600px; -o-min-width:600px; -webkit-min-width:600px; min-width:600px;">
                <tr class="rowClass">
                    <td><div><input name="inputName" value="My Name"></input></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="AddNew" colspan="42"> + </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="addType2" class="AddNew">+</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    ....
```

The cells for addType2 and addType1 are no longer being generated static.

Comment: Is this something you want to run on only one particular cell, or all cells? It might be easier to target the table itself and then down to the cells for you selector

Comment: I could change it to trigger from the table level, yes, but that would be a longer/messier selector. If I have a table cell with a defined id, I shouldn't have to do that. But to answer your question this is just one cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a data arrtibute to your table cell.

```
<td data-role="newID" id="ctl00_MainContent_tbTab_tbPanel_AccordionPane3_content_tableCellId" class="AddNew">+</td>

$("td[data-role='newID']").click(function () {
           //stuff
            });
```

Comment: I haven't used data-role before, but I would need this id to be unique. Any idea why the ID attribute would be generated dynamically?

Comment: Most likely has to do with the C#/.NET framework. A static HTML table would not have this problem.

Comment: The table is static, but there are cells and rows which are added/removed. The cell in question is never changed, however.

Comment: I updated the question with the full table. If there's anything else I can provide that will help please let me know.

Comment: I think its the ClientIDMode="Static" .. This does not make it static. It will take the ID passed from the controller over the ID on the table.

Comment: If I don't add that, the table's id is dynamically generated and my code won't work. It's just the same problem on the cell level.